# Ui-router using parent view but not as a layout

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Hello when i have this states defined:

```
.state('locations', {
    url: '/locations',
    templateUrl: '/templates/locations/index.html',
    controller: 'LocationsCtrl'
 })
.state('locations.show', {
    url: '/{location_id}',
    templateUrl: '/templates/locations/show.html'
});
```

How can i have `/templates/locations/index.html` to show for example a list of all locations,
but `templates/locations/show.html` to show a view of the location, but not nested inside the view of `index.html`. Basically i want the routes nested, but not the views.

Answer (score 0):

I just worked on an example similar to yours

`.state('overview', {
    url: '/all',
    templateUrl: '_/partial/overview/all.html',
    controller: 'homeCtrl'
})`

`.state('places', {
    url: '/:id/place',
    templateUrl: '_/partial/details/detail-place.html',
    controller: function($scope, $stateParams) {
        $scope.path = $scope.paths[$stateParams.id];
   }
})`

In your case

`.state('locations', {
    url: '/locations',
    templateUrl: '/templates/locations/index.html',
    controller: 'LocationsCtrl'
 })`

`.state('show', {
    url: '/{location_id}',
    templateUrl: '/templates/locations/show.html'
});`

That means the **show** state shouldn't be nested under **locations**.

Comment: But I want my route to be nested so /locations/{location_id} and i believe there are other nice things coming from nesting like I would be able to nest other things like /locations/{location_id}/menu/{menu_id}/items ... and so on